# Delete files with names that appear to begin with '?' in command line

Tags: debian, command-line, delete, nemo

I am running under Debian stable, Cinnamon DE and I have some files that I would like to delete with a command line (for now I delete these files with Nemo).

For example, these `.txt` files begin with '?' in the shell and in Nemo this '?' is replaced by a carriage return:

```
$@debian: ls
ssolveIncpUL46pK  ?ssolveIncpUL46pK.txt
```

[image: nemo]

I tried:

```
 rm ?ss*
 rm \?ss*
 rm \ ss*
```

Comment: Most likely, rather than `?`, it's a non-printable character that `ls` renders as `?`. What's the output of `ls | sed -n l`?

Comment: what about `rm "?FileName"` or `find . -name "\?*" -exec rm {} \;` _rm_ has not regex type

Comment: @HosseinVatani `rm` does not parse `?` or `*`, but the shell expands these globs before `rm` executes.

Comment: @ kevin-kruse yes, I meant he should not try to pass regex phrase to **rm**

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Maybe `ls -Q` would work better in Debian.

Comment: If you take the time to search... https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28983/22142 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402558/22142 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33483/22142 and plenty of others...

Comment: @isaac, better as `LC_ALL=C ls -Q` as there are plenty of Unicode characters that would result in ambiguous output with GNU `ls -Q`. Those should be OK with GNU `sed -n l`, but you would also need `LC_ALL=C` with some other `sed` implementations. It's true that newline characters would be a problem with `ls | sed -n l`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Care to give a couple of examples of ambiguous output of Unicode?

Comment: @isaac, see with `touch $'\ue9' $'e\u301' $'foo\u200bbar' foobar; ls -Q` and the many other "invisible" characters, or the many characters that look the same or are the same but meant to be used in different contexts (like `U+00C5` vs `U+212B` or the mathematical letters...).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The intent of using `-Q` is to expose what is the `?` encoding. This works reasonably well for humans, where a human could differentiated the filenames. That human language has confusing characters (like a Cyrillic а ($'\U430') and a Latin a ($'\U61')) that may "look" exactly the same is a different problem for which there is no simple solution. In any case, I find `\303\251` much more difficult to process visually than `é` in everyday use. Programs and scripts do not have that problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In looking back at this issue I find that it happens that none of your example filenames are encoded with a `?` with ls. So, `ls -Q` is not a solution for your problem.

Comment: Note the `ls` options `--show-control-chars`, `--hide-control-chars` (`-q`) and `--escape` (`-b`).

Comment: @isaac Here a possible explanation could be `$'\ufeff\nssolveIncpUL46pK.txt'` (with a UTF-8 BOM as sometimes found at the start of strings coming from the Microsoft world) which would show as `?ssolveIncpUL46pK.txt` (and `"\nssolveIncpUL46pK.txt"` with `ls -Q` and `"\357\273\277\nssolveIncpUL46pK.txt"` with `LC_ALL=C ls -q`) but not match the `?ss*` as there are two characters before `ss`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There are three levels here IMO. (1) In general the file names should be meaningful to users (otherwise we would just use the inode number). (2) If the name may be confusing, it may help to use `ls -Q` (not `-q` as in your comment as it means something different) and (3) If both tests fail, then use something like `ls | od -c`  or even `ls | od -tx1c` as a tool of last resort. I really dislike the use of LC_ALL=C for everything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The character is not a question mark. The `ls` utility will replace non printable characters with `?`.  It is further unclear whether the non printable character really is the *first* character in the filename or whether there may be one or several spaces before that.

Would you want to delete both those files, you could match the "bad part" with `*` and then specify the rest of the visible filename more closely:

```
rm -i ./*ssolve*
```

This would first expand the given pattern to all the filenames matching it, and then `rm` would remove them.  Be more specific and specify a longer part of the filename if there are files that you *don't* want to delete that matches the above short pattern, e.g. with

```
rm -i ./*ssolveIncpUL46pK*
```

This is assuming that you are located in the same directory as the files that you want to delete.

The `-i` option to `rm` makes it ask for confirmation before actually deleting anything.

Comment: The next question would be: why does `*ssolve*` match it when `?ss*` doesn't?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Because `?` does not match enough of the "bad part" of the filename. It may have something to do with multi-byte characters? Or it may simply be that there's a space before the non printable character. You're better than me with that sort of thing.

Comment: We'll probably never know unless the OP posts the output of `ls | sed -n l`.

Comment: Might want to do `echo ./*ssolve*` before the `rm`... *just in case*.

Answer (score 26):

The appropriate way to remove these kind of files is by using the `inode` value of the file.

Use the following command to  get `inode` value

```
 ls -li 

 12582925 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   646 May 23 02:19 ?ssolveIncpUL46pK.txt
```

The first field of the longlisted result is inode value.

Then use the find command to delete the file w.r.t inode.

```
find . -inum 12582925 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: This would be appropriate if no part of the filename could be matched with a filename globbing pattern, and if the `find` implementation on the system in question supports the nonstandard `-inum` predicate (which e.g. GNU `find` does).

Comment: This is actually unsafe. More than one file can have the same inode (using hard links). So instead of deleting just the file with the apparent question mark in it, you would be deleting that file and all the other files with the same inode number, in that directory and in any descendent subdirectories.

Comment: @Flimm `ls -li` will tell you whether the file has any hard links. (If the number immediately before `root  root` is `1`, then there are no hard links).

Comment: @craq Actually, I think this may be unsafe even in the case where `ls` is showing only 1 hard link. This is because two separate files with separate data entries can actually share the same inode number if they are on different mounted filesystems, I think. You should probably use the `-x` or `-xdev` option to avoid this (although you still have the problem of the previous comment.)

Comment: @Flimm inodes belong to one filesystem only, and it is not possible to hardlink across filesystems. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290525/why-are-hard-links-only-valid-within-the-same-filesystem or https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/why-isnt-it-possible-to-create-hard-links-across-file-system-boundaries.html

Comment: @craq What Flimm is getting at is that an inode `n` may be allocated on several different mounted filesystems, for very different files. Having inode 1234 on one filesystem does not exclude that the same inode, 1234, exists in another.

Comment: @Kusalananda, wow, I never thought of that. Now I agree that deleting by inode is very dangerous. The files would be completely unrelated, so you'd probably never even realise that you'd deleted more than you thought.

Comment: @Flimm see above (I can only notify one person per comment). That new question you asked really helped clarify this for me too. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Flimm What if additional limitations are placed on the search, say inode value of x and within directory y, would that then be OK?

Answer (score 12):

It is not recommended to use a `*` to remove files. It could match more than you like.

Being in Debian, the `ls` (from GNU) command is able to print the values of the files in quoted form<sup>[**1**]</sup>:

```
$ ls -Q
"\nssolve"  "\n\nssolve"  "y"  "z"
```

Or, even better, list files with quoted names and inodes:

```
$ ls -iQ
26738692 "\nssolve"  26738737 "\n\nssolve"  26738785 "y"  26738786 "z"
```

Then, use rm with the inode number to ensure that only the correct files are removed:

```
$ find . -xdev -inum 26738737 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

The call to find is limited to one filesystem (`-xdev`) to avoid matching a file on other filesystem with the same inode number.
Note also that `rm` is being called with the `-i` (interactive) option, so it will ask in the command line if each file should be erased.

---

<sup>[**1**]</sup> Note that this do not solve the problem with visually confusing characters like a Cyrillic `а` ($'\U430') and a Latin `a` ($'\U61') that look exactly the same but are not. To have a better look at the bytes that a filename is using we need to use an hex viewer;

```
$ touch а a é $'e\U301' $'\U301'e
$ ls
a  ́e  é  é  а              # what you "see" here depends on your system.

$ printf '<%s>' * | od -An -c
   <   a   >   < 314 201   e   >   <   e 314 201   >   < 303 251
   >   < 320 260   >
```